SphinxQL MATCH with or operator
I'm running this query
SELECT * FROM stockcategories_fr WHERE MATCH('@mycolumn ^t-shirt|^tee-shirt|^ tee-shirt|^ t-shirt');
It returns results :
T-shirts
T-shirts enfant
...
But if I run this query
SELECT * FROM stockcategories_fr WHERE MATCH('@mycolumn ^tee-shirt|^ tee-shirt|^t-shirt|^ t-shirt');
It returns no result.
I just changed the order of OR conditions in the MATCH clause.
For further information, mycolumn does not contain "tee-shirt" words.
Am i doing something wrong ?
Finally I put parenthesis on each word and it works.
SELECT * FROM stockcategories_fr WHERE MATCH('@mycolumn ^(tee-shirt)|^ (tee-shirt)|^(t-shirt)|^ (t-shirt)');

Sounds like you DONT have - in your charset_table - its not by default!
... so its treated as a word seperator. So
MATCH('@mycolumn ^t-shirt|^tee-shirt|^ tee-shirt|^ t-shirt');

is interpreted as
MATCH('@mycolumn ^t (shirt|^tee) (shirt|^) tee (shirt|^) t shirt');

OR has low precedence (less than sperator) hence the need to add explicit brackets.
(Note that whitespace/sepeators at the start (or inanywhere) is NOT indexed at all, so ^ t doesnt work. The ^ operator is ignored. And ^t would match if t is the first word, even if there is whitespace there.
So might as well simplify to
MATCH('@mycolumn (^tee-shirt)|(^t-shirt)'

Although might be maybe you intend to use pphrase operator
MATCH('@mycolumn "^tee-shirt"|"^t-shirt"'

So it would only match shirt immiidatelly following the t. (so it wouldn't match say t bone steak shirt)

Thank you for this information. It helps to understand how it works.
